# JWT giving user_not_found error

Tags: php, authentication, jwt

I'm getting user_not_found error and I think I am doing something wrong with my token generation. I am using mongodb and I have a collection for users and a collection for authInfo. The authInfo contains the user id and the hash and other auth related stuff. I just added the auth collection in and I had the tokens working when I was just storing everything in the user collection so I think there is some issue with using a different collection than the users collection

Signin function:

```
public function checkLogin(Request $request) {
  $credentials = $request->json()->all();

  $authInfo = AuthInfo::where('email', $credentials['email'])->first();

  if (!is_null($authInfo) and Hash::check($credentials['password'], $authInfo->hash)) {
    $token = $this->generateToken($authInfo->user_id);

    return Response::json(['token' => $token->get()]);
  }

  return Response::json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
}
```

generateToken function:

```
public function generateToken($userId)
{
    $payload = JWTFactory::make(['id' => $userId]);
    $token = JWTAuth::encode($payload);
    return $token;
}
```

my jwt.php setting

```
'user' => 'App\Models\User', 'identifier' => '_id'
```